# Mystery code in PHP

Tags: php, sql, loops, while-loop

This chunk of code was found in a script someone else wrote that I was asked to edit. It doesn't appear to be doing anything.. I'm wondering why on earth it was there and if something somewhere in the world would go terribly wrong if I remove it..

Am I missing something?

```
//begin mystery code - i have no idea what this chunk of code is doing..
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$i++;
}
}
//end mystery code
```

`$result` is not referenced anywhere else..

Comment: Basically what it does is it checks if there is an outcome of that result, and it does more then that, it runs through the loop. However, it doesnt seem to print / echo or execute anything beyond that. it just does i++, which just increases the i value. So yea, if I look at this, its just bogus cod, in plain common sense. I gotta say though, I have to see the full code in order to place this into context.

Comment: @Dorvalla I didn't even think about that, and now that you mention it I did find a `for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {` a little further down. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does two things:

1. Increasing `$i` per row.
2. Storing each row into `$row` and finally `false` into it.

So finally it sets:

- `$i` to the number of rows.
- `$row` to `false`

But do not wonder about crap code much. Improve it instead:

```
$i   = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = false;
```

Also encapsulate `mysql_*` calls so you can easily replace them later. You should also handle the error case if the query fails.

Answer (score 7):

It's counting the number of columns in a database table `$table`, and putting the value in `$i`

Presumably, `$i` is used later for something?

Answer (score 0):

only thing it seems to do is to count number of columns in $i. If $i is not used anywhere in the script you can remove this code.

also look for $row and $result variable uses in the script if none code can be removed.